# Screen not showing up when using Stack.Navigator in expo

Tags: react-native

I am new to app development and learning react-native using youtube tutorials.

I am trying to use `Stack.Navigator` for navigation and when I run the app using Expo Go on my mobile, nothing shows up. I don't see any compilation errors. Expo Go reloads the screen. But, nothing shows up on the screen. It is blank.

Here's the code:

App.js

```js
import SignInScreen from '../screens/SignInScreen';


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const Navigation = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
                <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignInScreen} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

export default Navigation;
```

In App.js, if I change it to a text and reload, I see my app shows up as Navigation on the screen. Would appreciate any help.

```js
const Navigation = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Text>Navigation</Text>

        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};
```

Comment: what does `SignInScreen` look like?

Comment: SignInScreen.js looks something like this:

Comment: Did you forget to paste the link?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Navigation from './Navigation';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      < Navigation />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
  }
});
```

YOUR CODE IN APP.JS SHOULD LOOK LIKE THIS IF YOU ARE IMPORTING NAVIGATION FROM SOME FILE.